# CAPTCHA is not visible at frontend login/register form for RWD theme

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, captcha

I’ve installed magento community edition version 1.9.0.0 and have found that when I set the new captcha feature under System>Configuration>Customer>Customer Configuration>CAPTCHA

I set the captcha to be used on create user and forgot password forms. Tested Create New Account form on frontend and found that the captcha box does not appear at all but when you fill in the form and submit and error message comes back saying that "incorrect captcha".

Its looking for the captcha but not allowing it to be visible for me to fill box in?

Where do I go to make captcha visible in frontend?

I did delete cache and cleared sessions and logged out and logged back in, just not there.

Comment: check the css like it will hide or not ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, and css is not hiding it...

Comment: getting some JS error in console?

Comment: No, Not getting JS error as well

Comment: then It will may conflict with theme please change to default them and test

Comment: It is issue with Magento rwd theme, When I switched from magento rwd theme to default theme, Captcha appeared. But when I switched again into magento rwd theme captcha disappeared. what could be the issue with theme???

Comment: may be..............

Comment: why don't you try https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly the RWD theme has been implemented without captcha. See notes from the [design guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide) section `Exceptions to Responsive Web Design`.

They have managed this by providing an empty layout.xml file for the captcha module under `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/captcha.xml`. What you could try is to disable this file and so it will fall back to the default `captach.xml` and see if this works.

Sadly I have not tried this as yet.

Comment: Thanks buddy...

That worked :)

Comment: @HarishKumar glad that it worked, not sure if this will have any side issues as the design is very different.

Answer (score 0):

Check disk space from your server. After you free some space, you will need to reboot and check again.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for 1.9.3.2 all.

I renamed the file captcha.xml to something else and it worked.

1. I tried **magecomp** and was of no use as you register with them and they let you download a tar file that  with no instructions. Waste of time.
2. I tried **amasty** too with no luck.

All i did was rename the captcha file and flush the cache. Thats important. Then i enabled the captcha in system>configuration>customer configuration. I used to get a lot of bot registrations and the spam registrations from ru sites have stopped.

Captcha issue solved.