# Activated Captcha in Admin but it is not visible on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, captcha

https://sciencellonline.com/customer/account/create/

When I try to register for an account, the captcha is not visible and gives an error saying "incorrect Captcha".

I deleted the captacha.xml and Captacha folder from RWD theme and copied them into custom and base folder. still no go.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find out how to fix it?
thanks

Comment: So sounds like you did what was directed per this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40788/captcha-is-not-visible-at-frontend-login-register-form-for-rwd-theme Can you give details of the actual locations where you copied the files to?
Possible your resulting locations are not correct?
Did you clear all cache after this (especially layout cache)?